# How to match unicode character code point 12288 using regexp

Tags: ruby, regex, unicode

I found a blank character in user input text (shown as blank space in database and in webpage) and I would like to filter it out.

The unicode code point of that character I get is `12288` ( I think it's this character: [codepoints.net/U+12288](http://codepoints.net/U+12288), am I right? ).

How could I match it using RegExp in Ruby?

Thanks a lot for your help.

**UPDATES:**

Hi Guys, Thank you very much. I really learned a lot from your replies, but it's still not working.

I found that the character in my user input is not character [codepoints.net/U+12288](http://codepoints.net/U+12288), but calling `.codepoints` it returns `12288` so matching `\u12288` is not working. Why is that?

```
> str = note.public_stripped_content
=> "　　权谋术，在古代称之为帝王术..."
> str.encoding
=> #<Encoding:UTF-8>
> str[0].codepoints
=> [12288]
> "\u12288"
=> "ረ8"
> "\u12288"[0]
=> "ረ"
> "\u12288"[1]
=> "8"
> "\u12288"[0].codepoints
=> [4648]
> "\u12288"[1].codepoints
=> [56]
```

Following is what I've done from Rails console. ( You could ignore the Chinese characters and the problematic characters are the leading blanks. )

```
> str = note.public_stripped_content
=> "　　权谋术，在古代称之为帝王术..."
> str.encoding
=> #<Encoding:UTF-8>
> str[0].codepoints
=> [12288]
> str.delete("\u12288")
=> "　　权谋术，在古代称之为帝王术..."
> str[0].codepoints
=> [12288]
> print /\u12288/.match(str)
=> nil
> str.gsub(/\p{Cuneiform}/u,'')
=> "　　权谋术，在古代称之为帝王术..."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`codepoints` returns an array of integers, that are printend as decimal values. In string literals you must use hexadecimal values to specify characters by code point. You can `map` the result of `codepoints` like this:

```
string = "权谋术，在古代称之为帝王术..."
string.codepoints 
# =>  [12288, 12288, 26435, ... ]
string.codepoints.map { |c| c.to_s(16) }
# => ["3000", "3000", "6743", ... ]
```

The actual codepoint you need is 3000. If you want to remove just it, you don't need a regexp, a call to `delete` (or `delete!`, if appropriate) will do:

```
string.delete("\u3000")
# => "权谋术，在古代称之为帝王术..."
```

**Update**: to specify a codepoint that is more than four (hex) digits long you must wrap it in braces:

```
"\u12288".codepoints # => [4648, 56]
"\u{12288}".codepoints # => [74376]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also do this by matching it's General Category or Script if it is truly coming through as unicode.

```
str = "FooBar"
```

**By Category**: [Regex101 Example](https://regex101.com/r/jK1bU6/1)

```
#match by category Other Letter (Lo)
str.gsub(/\p{Lo}/u,'')
```

**By Script**: [Regex101 Example](https://regex101.com/r/sO9lG6/2)

```
#match by script Cuneiform
str.gsub(/\p{Cuneiform}/u,'')
```

Answer (score 1):

I can think of [`#tr!`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/String.html#method-i-tr-21) :

```
>> string = "foo\u12288bar"
=> "fooረ8bar"
>> string.tr!("\u12288","")
=> "foobar"
>> string
=> "foobar"
```

Comment: Thanks, but I just found that my problematic character is not `\u12288` but `.codepoints` returns `12288` in ruby. I am quite confused, would you help me again? I've added updates in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Because you have an int value of 12288 and \u takes four hex digits. Try:  \u3000